# Why do I have a syntax error on my print function?

Tags: python, syntax-error, python-2.x

I'm trying to learn to program and I've gotten stuck on this piece of code

```
if 0 <= option < len(names)
    print names[option]
elif option == 99:
    quit
else:
    print "That is not a valid option!"
```

When trying to run the program I get a syntax error on the first print command, and I've searched for it for like an hour or two now but I just don't see what's wrong? Please help me.

Comment: Because you miss `:` after first `if`.

Comment: Hour or two... Now you are just blatantly lying, aren't you?

Comment: I've added the : after the first if statement and now it gives me a syntax error on that line of code?     if 0 <= option < len(names):
                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: By the way, what is the IDE that you use? Errors such as those may be avoided by the IDE hints. @pokemonfan

Comment: why not learn the python syntax well first:)

Comment: well I had to google what an IDE is but I think the IDE I use is notepad++

Comment: What is the syntax error? `IndentationError`?

Comment: it's not an indentationerror I think, it just says SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @pokemonfan I suggest [LiClipse](http://www.liclipse.com/)

Answer (score 5):

```
if 0 <= option < len(names):
                           ↑
```

Comment: Gift for Christmas: Sexy arrow ↑

Comment: You should accept this answer and post a new question for your new problem.